# click listener in OnBindViewholder recyclerview android

Tags: java, android, methods, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

In the below code 'setlisteners' method is called every time,should'nt value of position change?
There is only one method'setlisteners'in which parameter position is passed,but when in log ,i see that whenever click event happens on my buttons,it shows correct position. should'nt position overwrite itself and show incorrect position because click event can happen at any time ,by that time value of position will have changed?

> **let's suppose 5 views have been binded and i click on the first
>   itemview,then should'nt it show me the last position held by the last
>   binded itemview?**

```
 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {


     setListeners(holder,position);


    }

private void setListeners(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.updownarrow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.e("ddfg",""+position);

            }
        });
        holder.leftlayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
```

position will hold the position of the last holder which was bind in onBindViewHolder, since my View does not call onBindViewHolder when i click on it,should'nt position hold the position last binded and show only that one position whenever any view gets clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position in `onBindViewHolder` is the same as the position in your adapter/data set. Your Click Listener is being set with the `position` the individual ViewHolder represented in your data set at the time of binding. Even though the click event isn't being called until after all your Views are binded, each function instance was already set up to use the corresponding position each view was set with.

If each View shared the same instance of a Click Listener, then you would only get the last position. But, each View holds its own instance of a Click Listener.

Answer (score 0):

No, `position` will hold the position of the last holder which was bin in `onBindViewHolder`, since your `View` does not call `onBindViewHolder` when you click on it.

There are many possibilities to retrieve the correct position - for example if you set & get the position in the  `Views` `tag` or search for the surrounding `ViewHolder` and check its position in the adapter or layout.

Comment: you have said" position will hold the position of the last holder which was binded in onBindViewHolder".Then let's suppose 5 views have been binded and i click on the first itemview,then should'nt it show me the last position held by the last binded itemview?

Comment: Yes, it should do. But this does not mean, that your last list item is the last binded view.

Answer (score 0):

Dont use the position in onBindViewHolder. use this:

```
final int adapterPosition = viewholder.getAdapterPosition();
// do what ever with it
```